# Install Stata16 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation

While installing Stata16 I've encountered issues with `libpng12` and `libncurses`.

Sadly `libpng12` is no longer part of `universe` ppa which means it needs a fix.

---

original error messages

```
./stata: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

```
./stata: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

First one is easily resolved by installing `libncurses` for 64 bit system appropriate one is:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5
```

Second issue is solved by adding appropriate ppa fixing installation issues of older deb packages originating in changes in directory structure.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12
sudo apt install libpng12-0
```

Finally a noncricial error of missing `libcanberra` can be resolved via

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

Hopefully this will save someones time in the future.

Comment: Under Ubuntu 23.10, I get `E: Unable to locate package libncurses5`